# A Pathfinder creature from the Cthulhu mythos

Tags: pathfinder-1e, content-identification

I remember having read a few months ago in a bestiary preview something about a creature taken from the Ctulhu mythos. It was a unique named monster with a very high CR (>20).
It looked humanoid with a pale tentacly-face.

I crawled the Internet yesterday but I couldn't find it. Can someone help me? I am more precisely looking for the illustration of the creature but I think I can find it from the name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a small list of all creatures from cthulhu mythos published on bestiary books:

- Bestiary - Ghoul, Shoggoth, Skum (Deep One)
- Bestiary 2 - [Denizen of Leng](http://projects.inklesspen.com/fatal-and-friends/images/51413c8c873f6deb91b034504bb4a9c0a0258d8cc022ec3fa260784f0e51fab2.png), [Gug](http://projects.inklesspen.com/fatal-and-friends/images/3377a0de3877da477f141cece4c31617292ca67b598a71498be03bedf758d37c.png), Hound of Tindalos, Leng Spider, [Serpentfolk](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/87/9a/a8/879aa864c8914258138dcb9c277fb57d.jpg), [Shantak](http://pathfinderwiki.com/mediawiki/images/thumb/c/cb/Shantak.jpg/250px-Shantak.jpg)
- Bestiary 3 - [Moon-Beast](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/40/1e/29/401e295f17294e6fce21cc8e3392f3cc.jpg), Voonith, Yithian, Zoog
- Bestiary 4 - Bhole (CR 17) - [Colour Out of Space](http://orig00.deviantart.net/02cc/f/2011/172/4/b/4b3c09fd445d317ed56bd77d310bc77d-d3jlcrz.jpg) (CR 10) - [Demon Lord, Dagon](https://i.warosu.org/data/tg/img/0290/74/1388111704193.png) (CR 28) - Elder Thing (CR 5) - [Flying Polyp](http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/kJAAAMXQVERSsxoP/s-l300.jpg) (CR 14) - [Great Old One, Bokrug](https://i.warosu.org/data/tg/img/0319/71/1399452219472.png) (CR 27) - [Great Old One, Cthulhu](https://i.warosu.org/data/tg/img/0319/71/1399450553569.png) (CR 30) - [Great Old One, Hastur](https://i.warosu.org/data/tg/img/0319/71/1399451235911.png) (CR 29) - [Mi-Go](http://orig02.deviantart.net/ef35/f/2011/172/1/4/1421ec8fb79499e1ad02745584872700-d3jkg3s.jpg) (CR 6) - [Nightgaunt](http://orig00.deviantart.net/5190/f/2012/354/9/8/9895f2e6798a3db9a06f7a45f528ca20-d5okqly.jpg) (CR 4) - [Ratling](https://i.warosu.org/data/tg/img/0281/09/1383625373055.png) (CR 2) - [Spawn of Yog-Sothoth](https://i.warosu.org/data/tg/img/0319/71/1399454141205.png) (CR 10) - [Star Spawn of Cthulhu](http://orig07.deviantart.net/5fed/f/2011/179/2/b/2b4a7f9ff7ea11bf92d0d596eed476f8-d3k8j5k.jpg) (CR 20)
- Bestiary 5 - Deep One (CR 1) - Deep One Hybrid (template) - Elder Deep One (CR 14) - Leng Ghoul (CR 10)

There are also creatures that are unique from paizo books and have a mythos appearance, like the [Venedaemon](http://paizo.com/image/content/PathfinderCampaignSetting/PZO9239-Venedaemon.jpg), but that are not part of the cthulhu mythos.

You could also be looking at the preview image of the [Great Old One Tawil at'Umr](http://static3.paizo.com/image/content/PathfinderRPG/PZO1137-GreatOldOneTawilAtUmr.jpg), that was [previewed for bestiary 6](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ljoq?Demigods-of-Bestiary-6) few months ago.

Comment: Added the [blog link](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ljoq?Demigods-of-Bestiary-6).

Answer (score 0):

The Bestiary 5 book has a number of [Lovecraft inspired monsters](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary5/index.html), including Deep Ones, building on some of the monster groundwork laid in the Bestiary 4 book, which features the [Great Old Ones](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/aberrations/great-old-ones/).

Cthulhu (from Bestiary 4) fits the current description (Pale, Tenticle Face, CR > 30).  Do you remember any additional details?

Comment: This answer doesn't identify the content in question.

Comment: Every bestiary has at least one creature from the cthulhu mythos.